# WebSocket connection failed

Tags: jsonrpc-api, websocket

What is the correct URL to use for wss connection? I'm getting this error:

`websocket.browser.js:47 WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/' failed`

My code used to work fine with these endpoints, but they give the same error now.

````
endpoints = [
  { url: 'https://raydium.rpcpool.com', weight: 100 },
  { url: 'https://solana-api.tt-prod.net', weight: 100 }
  { url: 'https://solana-api.projectserum.com', weight: 100 } ]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public RPCs don't have reliable socket support. There are free alternatives though that you can use which offer a few million free requests. For example:

- Helius https://www.helius.dev/
- Quicknode: https://www.quicknode.com/
- Hello moon: https://www.hellomoon.io/developers

and more